# How to make gifs "refresh" in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

So I have a function

```
                var $gifs = $('#stats-table img');
                $gifs.css('visibility','hidden');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $gifs.css('visibility','visible');
                    $gifs.each(function(){
                        var url = $(this).attr("src");
                        $(this).attr('src','');
                        $(this).attr('src',url);
                    });
                },900);
```

that makes a set of gifs begin their animated cycle. It works in Chrome and Firefox but not IE. Any ideas on how I can make this work across all known browswers?

Comment: Why is your code indented so far over?